# Printing Pandas DataFrame with only the last appended values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am collecting data from the web using Python and appending the data to a pandas dataframe.

I wanted to view the updated dataframe on the dos command prompt each time it is appended. This is what I am currently doing:

```
for i in range(0,len(Record_files)):
    os.system('cls')
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None,'expand_frame_repr', False):
        print(Database)
```

Since, the `Database` is too big, it scrolls most of the time continuously than just viewing the last updated entry.

For Example:

Let the initial data frame output be

```
    Time       Temperature
  12:34 PM         45 C
  12:37 PM         42 C
```

Now when new data gets appended, I want it to print it as:

```
    Time       Temperature
  12:34 PM         45 C [old]
  12:37 PM         42 C [old]
  12:42 PM         39 C [new]
```

I want only the [new] entry to printed as it is queued while the other [old] entries should remain on the screen. The issues with my current method of clearing the screen using os.system('cls') for every update is that, when the list gets more than the length of the terminal window it keeps on scrolling and its seems useless.

Comment: Do you mean something like [df.tail()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)?

Comment: No that would return only the last n rows of the dataframe, right? I want the entire database to be there... only the appended values should be printed on the screen whenever its updated..

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want "*entire* database" or "only the *appended* values" to be printed? These are contradicting things. Or do you mean that you want to print only *updated* records? Please, provide an example.

Comment: print(Database.tail(1))  - If there is guaranteed to be only a single row appended each time?

Comment: The best you're going to get is track datetime instead of just time.  Then filter rows for which the datetime column is greater than say 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you're maintaining unique indices in both frames, you can just subset the `old_df` by using the index of the `new_df`.

Let's say `new_df` is the DataFrame you appended.

```
old_df = old_df.append(new_df)
```

And now you want to see only the updated rows:

```
old_df.iloc[new_df.index, :]
```

There's no guarantee that screen still won't roll if your `new_df` is too big to fit on the screen! You could write a for loop with a user input to print batch of rows on entering some string to print the new_df in batches of 50 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted it to have it updated without rolling.